# Create an alert selecting combolist Acrobat JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, acrobat

I'm trying to make an alert if the user select a blank space in combo list, however I get the error window en every selection I make and not only my var a. I'm new about programming acrobat JavaScript, thanks because of your attention.

this is my script:

```
var Brand = this.getField("BrandList");
event.value = Brand.value;
if (event.value!="B000")
{
    var a=(Brand = "B000");
    var b=(Brand= ["B010"],["B020"],["B030"],["B040"],["B050"],["B051"],["B051"],["B052"],["B053"],["B054"],["B055"],["B060"],["B061"],["B062"],["B063"],["B064"],["B065"],["B070"]);

    if (a=true) {
        event.target = null;
        event.rc= null;
        event.action= null;
        event.change= "Brand";
        app.alert({
            cMsg: "The selection is not valid",
            cTitle: "Data Error",
            nIcon: 0,
            nType: 1
        });
    }
    if (b=true) {
        event.target = true;
        event.rc= true;
        event.action= true;}
}
```

Comment: Hint: `a=true` **assigns** `true` to `a`; Same as `Band=...`.

Comment: It got me a while to understand, thanks Passerby,

Comment: By the way this script helped me to create an alert if a certain value in the combo box is selected:                          if(event.value == " ") {
app.beep(1);
app.alert("Selection Is Not Valid",2);
event.rc = null;
defaultValue=="Brand Car";